# Passing both array and scalar to subroutine

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

First time posting here, hope that someone can help me. Im new with programming and perl, and currently taking a course at the university.

My question is about the following subroutine that takes an array and a scalar (string) as arguments. I call the subroutine with a reference to the array, and dereference in the subroutine.

The length of the array whose reference I pass as argument to the subroutine is not 0. The length of the array that I get after dereferencing in the subroutine is 0. I don't understand why.

```
sub calc_average {

    my @indexes = @{$_[1]};
    print @indexes."\n"; #test only
    my $line = $_[0];
    #my $sum = 0;
    #my @row=split(/\t/,$line);
    #for (my $i=0; $i<@indexes; $i++){
    #    my $sum = $sum + $row[$indexes[$i]];
    #}
    #my $average = $sum/scalar(@indexes);
    #print $average."\n"; #test only
    #return $average;
}
```

This prints 0. The subroutine is called with:

```
calc_average($line, \@GC_indexes)."\n";
```

`@GC_indexes` is not empty. `$line` is a line of text in a file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks fine, https://eval.in/544496

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that we can copy and paste verbatim and run on our own machines. The code you've shown isn't enough to reproduce your problem.

Comment: What are `$line` and `@row` for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`my $sum = $sum + $row[$indexes[$i]];` should not have the `my` declaration in the loop.

You are creating a new `$sum` for each iteration of the `for` loop (in the scope of the `for` loop). When the loop ends, the `$sum` created there goes out of scope and the program uses the `$sum` you created before the loop (which is equal to 0).

Comment: (As an aside, it could also be written `$sum += $row[$indexes[$i]];`)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'm just learning how to use local variables, this is the problem here! :D

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could pass the array to a sub function is as followed

```
calc_average($line,\@GC_indexes);

sub calc_average{
    my ($line,$index) = @_;
    my @indexes = @{$index};
    print scalar(@indexes); #should print the length of your array
```

}

You can fill in the rest, just thought I'd share.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of solutions you got *it looks fine to me* comments. Your question should have included a verifiable example. Please read [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Commenting out the code you know doesn't work won't help you find a solution: it leaves us nothing to work from. In this case all I had to do was remove your comments

Here's the MCVE for your question

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dump;

my $line = join "\t", 1 .. 100;
my @GC_indexes = (7, 14, 42);

print calc_average($line, \@GC_indexes), "\n";

sub calc_average {

    my @indexes = @{$_[1]};
    print @indexes."\n"; #test only
    my $line = $_[0];
    my $sum = 0;
    my @row=split(/\t/,$line);
    for (my $i=0; $i<@indexes; $i++){
        my $sum = $sum + $row[$indexes[$i]];
    }
    my $average = $sum/scalar(@indexes);
    print $average."\n"; #test only
    return $average;
}
```

#### output

```
3
0
0
```

As you have been told, the main problem is that you have declared a *new* `$sum` within your `for` loop. Each time around the loop the inner `$sum` is declared and starts with the value `undef`, then it is incremented by `$row[$indexes[$i]]` and it is discarded at the end of the loop block. You meant to use the *outer* `$sum` that you declared a few lines earlier

Please also note the following points

- You *must always* start every Perl program with `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'`. That will help immensely with a large number of trivial errors that you may otherwise overlook, and espceially should be in place before you ask others for help
- Use much more whitespace to make it clear to the eye where the fundamental units of your program start and stop. For instance, operators should be separated from their operands, and blocks should stand out distinctly from their surrounding code
- Arrays in scalar context evaluate to the number of elements in the array; when interpolated into a string they form a string separated by the contents of the built-in variable `$"` which is normally as single space, and in list context (as in the parameters to a subroutine call) they evaluate as a list of their elements

  That means `print @indexes."\n"` will print the number of elements in `@indexes` followed by a newline, whereas `print "@indexes\n"` will print the *contents* of `@indexes` with a newline, and `print @indexes, "\n"` will print all of the elements of the array (with no separator) and a newline

  I'm unsure which you meant here
- The C-style `for` loop is very rarely necessary. Usually you just need to iterate over a list. So `for (my $i=0; $i<@indexes; $i++)` is almost certainly better as `for my $i ( 0 .. $#indexes )`

  You should almost never need `$i++`. The form has been popularised by the name of the C++ language, but as well as incrementing `$i` is also has the burden of returning the value *before it was incremented*. Most modern languages will optimise that away but you shouldn't rely on it, and it also breaks the rule of putting the *verb* before the *noun*

  The expression `$#array` evaluates to the last index of `@array`. It was designed to be used for instances like this
- The expression `$sum/scalar(@indexes)` doesn't need the `scalar` operator. As disacussed before, `@array` in scalar context (provided by the division `/` operator) evaluates to the number of elements in `@array`, so all you need is `$sum/@indexes`

I've written this solution. Your own subroutine (with the comments removed) is `calc_average0`, while how I would write it is `calc_average1`. As I described, your own subroutine prints the number of elements in the array `@GC_indexes` passed by reference, followed by zero, because the outer `$sum` is never changed from its initialisation

I hope this helps

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dump;

my $line = join "\t", 1 .. 100;
my @GC_indexes = ( 7, 14, 42 );

calc_average0( $line, \@GC_indexes );
calc_average1( $line, \@GC_indexes );

sub calc_average0 {

    my @indexes = @{ $_[1] };
    print @indexes . "\n";    #test only
    my $line = $_[0];
    my $sum  = 0;
    my @row  = split( /\t/, $line );
    for ( my $i = 0; $i < @indexes; $i++ ) {
        my $sum = $sum + $row[ $indexes[$i] ];
    }
    my $average = $sum / scalar(@indexes);
    print $average. "\n";     #test only
    return $average;
}

sub calc_average1 {

    my ( $line, $indexes ) = @_;

    my @line = split /\t/, $line;

    my $sum = 0;
    $sum += $line[ $indexes->[$_] ] for 0 .. $#{$indexes};

    my $average = $sum / @$indexes;
    print "calc_average1: $average\n";    #test only

    return $average;
}
```

#### output

```
3
0
calc_average1: 22
```